Folium: How to add a polyline that pops up when a user hovers over it?
I want to create a polyline so that when the use hovers over its associated points/markers, a line is drawn from that pair of coordinates to another. This is what I have so far. I was considering doing GeoJSON to convert the pair of coordinates into a GeoJSON line object, but I feel like there might be a more straightforward way to go about?
I want it to look similar to this:

Image of desired map here
This is what I have so far.
for _, row in result_df.iterrows(): # _ = conventional placeholder for a value we will not be using

    # making marker at initial coordinates
    marker_init = folium.Marker(location=[row['Initial Latitude'], row['Initial Longitude']], tooltip=f"From {row['Initial Place']} to {row['Final Place']}", icon=folium.Icon(color='blue')).add_to(m_2)
    
    # make market at final coordinates
    folium.Marker(location=[row['Final Latitude'], row['Final Longitude']], tooltip=f"From {row['Initial Place']} to {row['Final Place']}", icon=folium.Icon(color='red')).add_to(m_2)

    # make poly line connecting initial and final coordinates
    poly = folium.PolyLine([[row['Initial Latitude'], row['Initial Longitude']], [row['Final Latitude'], row['Final Longitude']]], tooltip=f"From {row['Initial Place']} to {row['Final Place']}").add_to(m)
    
    # add popup of text to polyline
    popup = folium.Popup(f"From {row['Initial Place']} to {row['Final Place']}").add_to(poly)

    # trying to add poly line back to map so poly line and text pop up when user hovers over the initial coordinates (???0)
    popup = folium.Popup(poly).add_to(marker_init)
    popup.add_to(m_3)



m_3

But I get errors:
UndefinedError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/IPython/core/formatters.py in call(self, obj)
343             method = get_real_method(obj, self.print_method)
344             if method is not None:
--> 345                 return method()
346             return None
347         else:
9 frames
 in top-level template code()
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/jinja2/utils.py in from_obj(cls, obj)
81     @classmethod
82     def from_obj(cls, obj: F) -> t.Optional["_PassArg"]:
---> 83         if hasattr(obj, "jinja_pass_arg"):
84             return obj.jinja_pass_arg  # type: ignore
85
UndefinedError: 'None' has no attribute 'replace'

If it perhaps helps .. here is described how you can add a line (antpath in that case) by clicking a marker: https://stackoverflow.com/q/74436743/13843906
